# Хранимая процедура. Postgresql

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

пытаюсь сделать хранимую процедуру, которая по введению в нее двух параметров (цифры и буквы класса) выдаст нам кол.учеников в классе их кол. неуспевающих и кол. успевающих.
Вот, номер класса,буква и кол. учеников у меня все хорошо выводит, но есть проблемка в кол. неуспевающих и кол. успевающих. Не могу понять как их задать. Очень долго пытался в where вставить условия типо (mark<60 or mark>=60). Однако, никак не мог совместить это для успевающих и не успевающих. Поскажите как это можно сделать вообще...

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION public.сlass3(dname varchar,dname1 varchar)
RETURNS TABLE(numberr varchar(50), 
              letterr varchar(50),
              kol int, 
              kol_ne bigint,
              kol_ot bigint)
security definer
LANGUAGE plpgsql 
AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
select c.number, c.letter, c.kol_ychenuk, count(o.id_pupil), count(o.id_pupil)
from mark o,class c,pupil p
where c.number =dname 
  and c.letter =dname1 
  and mark <=60 
  and p.id_pupil = o.id_pupil  
  and c.id_class = p.class
group by c.number,c.letter,c.kol_ychenuk;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Вставьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос структуру ваших таблиц `mark`, `pupil` и `class` в виде `create table` выражений

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN mark<60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_losers` и аналогичное выражение для успевающих.